# Clean partition map before installing High Sierra

Tags: disk-utility, partition, high-sierra

I'm about to do a clean install of High Sierra on my iMac and I have a Bootcamp partition with Windows 10.

I've checked the partition map, there are a lot of partitions I don't know about and I would like to delete all the unnecesaty ones.

Here is my `diskutil list` result.

[image: diskutil list]

Comment: Can I assume the image you posted was taken while booted  to the USB installer?

Comment: yes, that's correct, the only ones that appear in my imac are disk0 and disk1. But when using disk utility I only see disk0

Comment: Interesting problem. Do you want to keep Core Storage? I am not sure why you are using Core Storage. You do not have a Fusion drive and you are not using encryption. The Disk Utility application only has the legacy "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" and new "APFS" options. Some users have reported problems booting back to macOS from Windows when APFS is used.

Comment: Hi David, this is the basic model iMac without Fusion Drive, and yes, I don't have encryption. I already backed up the data I needed from the mac partition, but I don't want to break the windows partition. I just want to delete the mac partitions, create a new one and install high sierra there. I've read about the problems and they are caused because windows can't read the APFS partitions, but that's ok with me, I use refind to manage boot. What I'm worried about is APFS not working properly with the HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disk0` is your physical internal disk.

- `disk1s1` is required by macOS. Windows also stores boot software in this partition.
- `disk1s2` is used by macOS. The partition is not used by Windows.
- `disk1s3` is used by macOS. The partition is not used by Windows.
- `disk1s4` is used by Windows. The partition is not used by macOS.
- `disk1s5` is used by Windows. The partition is not used by macOS.

`disk1` is virtual and exists because you are using core storage.

`disk2` is the USB macOS installer.

The rest of the disks and partitions only exist because you are booted to the macOS installer. **You should not try to delete these partitions**.

Basically, the installer creates virtual disks in your computer's volitile RAM memory. These disks are used for temporary file storage. For example, compressed files stored on the USB drive are decompressed and stored on these disks.

You should be able to delete `disk0s2` and `disk0s3` without affecting Windows. If for some reason Windows will not boot, then you will need to create a bootable USB Windows Installer to fix the problem. If necessary, you can do this from macOS. I would avoid deleting the macOS volume. Instead I would do the following.

1. Boot to the USB macOS installer.
2. Open the Disk Utility application.
3. Erase the macOS volume using the format "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)". This  should:

   - Remove Core Storage  on partition `disk0s2`.
   - Remove the "Recovery HD" volume on partition `disk0s3`.
   - Create a  "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" volume on a new partition.
4. Exit the Disk Utility application.
5. Restart and boot back to the USB macOS installer.
6. Install High Sierra on to the new volume. This should also create a new "Recovery HD" volume.

Comment: Sorry David, maybe my question was not clear enough. I now what those disks are. What I don't know is in my disk0 which partitions I can safely delete without corrupting my BootCamp partition in order to do make a clean install of macOS High Sierra.

Comment: I updated my answer.